# How to read local DB from Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have created an external sqlite database, filled with tables and data. Now I want to integrate this DB with a PhoneGap application. I want to fetch the data from this DB and display it on the android screen.

Currently, I have to use `window.openDatabase(database_name, database_version, database_displayname, database_size);` and `executeSql` functions to enter the data, which is very cumbersome. I also want to know is it possible to package this external DB in the Phonegap application (.apk)

Comment: Ok... I have found something that I am looking for at http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence) but I don't know where to put the code given in the above link. I am developing for Android and I have very less knowledge of JAVA

Comment: Check [this link](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html) It has all the steps to fix your problem.